# Disable login after blank screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 on my notebook and I am having difficulties finding some options. In "Settings -> Power -> Blank_Screen" is the option disable the monitor after a timeout. In 16.10 it was possible to activate the monitor again *without* the need for a password.

Every time the monitor goes 'blank' I need to reenter the password. With the 'dconf-editor' I already looked in in

> org.gnome.desktop.screensaver

Here I was able to disable the option to enter a password after suspend. Is the same possible when the system gets to the blank screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 20.04 you need to go to Settings → Privacy → Screen Lock and adjust the settings there.

[image]

Comment: works on Debian too